# Indexing Pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a Pytorch code which generates a Pytorch tensor in each iteration of for loop, all of the same size. I want to assign each of those tensors to a row of new tensor, which will include all the tensors at the end. In other works something like this

```
for i=1:N:
  X = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3], [3,2,5]])
  #Y is a pytorch tensor
  Y[i] = X
```

I wonder how I can implement this with Pytorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the tensors using [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat):

```py
tensors = []
for i in range(N):
  X = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [3,2,5]])
  tensors.append(X)
Y = torch.cat(tensors, dim=0)  # dim 0 is the rows of the tensor
```